# Generating client code from OpenAPI spec fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, openapi, swashbuckle

I stumbled across [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/generating-http-api-clients-using-visual-studio-connected-services/) and out of curiosity, I gave it try. I could successfully generate the OpenAPI spec as a JSON file from our ASP.NET Core Web API.

But when trying to create a *Connected Service* within Visual Studio 2019 to generate the client code from the OpenAPI spec, it fails with the following error:

```
NuGet.PackageManagement.PackageReferenceRollbackException: Package restore failed.
```

Any ideas what might be wrong? How can I determine which package is missing? And is it related to my OpenAPI spec or a problem of the Visual Studio workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the following error message when adding the *Connected Service*:

```
Warning MSB3106 Assembly strong name "C:\Users\ME\.nuget\packages\newtonsoft.json\12.0.3\lib\netstandard2.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(\). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(\).
```

By adding the following line to my project file, the error disappeared and I could successfully generate the client code:

```
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
```

Comment: Where did you find that error message? It's not working for me, but I don't see any error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try clearing the NuGet Cache? VS Tools > Options > Nuget Package Manager > General > Clear All Nuget Cache(s).

[image: Clear NuGet Package Cache]

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately, the error remains the same. The last line before the error occurs says `Installing package 'Newtonsoft.Json' with version '12.0.2'.`

Comment: Do you have Newtonsoft.Json already installed?

Comment: No, I hadn't. After explicitly adding v12.0.2, it is now working.